# C# CryptoStream equivalent in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I have a C# method for decryption, and I'm trying to convert it to a PHP equivalent.

Here's the method in C#:

```
public static string DecryptSHA256(string inputText, string key, string salt)
{
    string str2;
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);

    RijndaelManaged objA = new RijndaelManaged();
    objA.KeySize = 256;
    objA.BlockSize = 256;
    objA.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    objA.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    objA.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    objA.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("XzYAsLyfjPTTsrLfXoCUtfdcmbGLpRLO");

    ICryptoTransform transform = objA.CreateDecryptor(new PasswordDeriveBytes(objA.Key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), "SHA256", 2).GetBytes(objA.KeySize / 8), objA.IV);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] buffer3 = new byte[buffer.Length];
    stream2.Read(buffer3, 0, buffer3.Length);
    str2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer3).Replace("\0", "");
    return str2;
}
```

Here's a method call in C#:

```
string dc = DecryptSHA256("MzDF/4K2ueGDx3N9VXrPZZu2MnBIROn3XbllraO+KEA=", "eaf71972af77802e47b6d7a5f91330b6", "NCPPROJECT");
```

Who do i convert it into a PHP?
Here's what I've got so far:

```
$input = 'MzDF/4K2ueGDx3N9VXrPZZu2MnBIROn3XbllraO+KEA=';
$key = 'eaf71972af77802e47b6d7a5f91330b6';
$salt = 'NCPPROJECT';
$iv = 'XzYAsLyfjPTTsrLfXoCUtfdcmbGLpRLO';

function password_derive_bytes($key, $salt, $algo, $iterations, $length) {
    $h = $key . $salt;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $iterations; $i++) { 
        $h = hash($algo, $h, true);
    } 

    $a = unpack('c*', $h);

    return array_slice($a, 0, $length);
}

echo '<strong>PASSWORD DERIVE BYTES:</strong><br />';
$pdb = password_derive_bytes($key, $salt, "sha256", 2, 32);

for ($c = 0; $c < count($pdb); $c++) {
    $pdb[$c] = ($pdb[$c] < 0 ? 256 - ($pdb[$c] * -1) : $pdb[$c]);
    echo '    [' . $c . ']: ' . $pdb[$c] . '<br />';
}

$pdbs = implode(array_map("chr", $pdb));
$pdbs = base64_encode($pdbs);
echo 'PDBS: ' . $pdbs . '<br />';
```

That works fine, but how can I convert this part:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
byte[] buffer3 = new byte[buffer.Length];
stream2.Read(buffer3, 0, buffer3.Length);
str2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer3).Replace("\0", "");
return str2;
```

into a PHP equivalent?

Comment: you cant decode `sha`  not to mention the C# stuff looks like AES to me but I could be wrong.  (but `Rijndael` is kind of a give away)  `Rijndael (pronounced rain-dahl) is the algorithm that has been selected by the U.S. National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) as the candidate for the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)`

Comment: `sha256` is like only 64 chars long and is a ONE way hashing algo, AES is a symmetric block cypher.  You can try open_ssl, or PHPSecLib, stay away from `mycrypt` as its been removed for PHP7.2+

Comment: @Draško have you found any solution?

Comment: @userI no :( i gave up